# Wrong hour given by the expression "object.dt.hour"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dt, string-to-datetime

The code is returning the wrong hour at `09/04/2023 11:00:00`. It is returning me the hour 10 for some reason.

I have a date column in a excel sheet with every hour in 2023 (01/01/2023 01:00:00 till today) and I used these lines in my python code:

```
colunas_planilha2['Hora'] = pd.to_datetime(colunas_planilha2['Dia/Hora'])
colunas_planilha2['Hora dt'] = pd.to_datetime(colunas_planilha2['Dia/Hora']).dt.hour
```

But I notice something wrong at `09/04/2023 11:00:00`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwAk2.png

for some reason it's returning me the hour 10

Why did it happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Try changing the column names to ones not containing /

Comment: @gtomer Why would the column name matter?

Comment: I suspect this is a timezone issue, or maybe Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Barmar - special char. in column name sometime do weird things

Comment: @gtomer I find that very difficult to believe. Can you provide an example or reference?

Comment: You can control `import time

print(time.strftime("Date and Time Zone: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z, The time offset: %z", time.localtime())) ` to see what time zone you are working.

Comment: @Hermann12 it printed "Date and Time Zone: 2023-07-31 14:56:12 E. South America Standard Time, The time offset: -0300"

im brazilian. if it is a timezone issue how can i fix that?

Comment: @Barmar according to google, Brazil doesn't have daylight savings

Comment: @RodrigoAraujoMendes are you in Brazil?